# Add CSS style to every 3rd element

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="view-row view-row-1">
    <div class="view-row view-row-2">
    <div class="view-row view-row-3">
    <div class="view-row view-row-4">
    <div class="view-row view-row-5">
    <div class="view-row view-row-6">
</div>
```

I need to add a CSS style to rows - `2, 5, 8, 11, 14` and so on. There may be a lot of `.view-row-number` elements, 40 for example.

```
$('.content .view-row').each( function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('view-row-2') ) {
        $(this).css('padding-left', '7px');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass(?)) {
    }
});
```

What is the best method of achieving this?

Comment: Use this - http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Make sure to accept one of the answers

Comment: ofc, i will do it. many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `nth-child` selector like this:

```
$("#content .view-row:nth-child(3n-1)").addClass("highlight");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkp2B/)

You can then put the required styling in the CSS class to maintain a good separation of concerns.

Comment: if jquery is not necessary, you can do it on just css => http://jsfiddle.net/DwHFb/

Comment: yep i did it with css), but anyway its useful to know about jquery solution

Comment: @neok Glad you got it working. Just be aware that the CSS version won't work in FF3 or anything less than IE9. The jQuery way will work in everything.

Answer (score 4):

You'v got iterator in cycle, so you can do that:

```
$('.content .view-row').each( function(i) {
    if ((i + 2) % 3 == 0) { $(this).css('padding-left', '7px'); }
});
```

or use css3 selector nth-of-type:

```
$('.content .view-row:nth-of-type(3n-1)').css('padding-left', '7px');
```

Comment: I think that he uses drupal. Drupal uses old version of jquery and I'm not sure that css3 selectors will work with it.

Comment: You don't need the `each()` iterator with the `nth` selector as jQuery will automatically apply the `css` specified to all elements in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Don't over complicate it -

```
$('#content div:nth-child(3n-1)').addClass('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 2;
$('.content .view-row').each( function(i) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('view-row-'+num) ) {
                num = num + 3;
                $(this).css('padding-left', '7px');
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass(?)) {

            }
           });
```